# passing template args to std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11

Im having a little problem passing the args to my std::thread that calls the template function.

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
void start(int interval, F func, A&&... args)
{
    if (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        stop();
    };
    _running.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    _thread = std::thread([this, interval, func, args]()
    {
        while (_running.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
            func(std::forward<A>(args)...);

            for (int i = 0; (i <= (interval / 200)) && _running.load(std::memory_order_acquire); i++)
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    });
}
```

edit:
Added a little more detail
I should be able to pass any function to "start" with any ammount or args

```
void ThreadProc(HWND hwnd)
{
    Beep(1000, 100);
}

start(2000, ThreadProc, hwnd);
```

error:

```
error C3520: 'args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
    note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void CallBack::start<void(__cdecl *)(HWND),HWND&>(int,F,HWND &)' being compiled
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              F=void (__cdecl *)(HWND)
    1>          ]
```

Comment: What does "a little problem" mean?

Comment: Can you make a *minimal* example of your problem?

Comment: @JamesRoot i updated my post.

Comment: @ramafe You added what you want and where an error happens, but still not what the error is.

Comment: this is not whole error, just end of its description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_thread = std::thread([this, interval, func, &args...]()
```

Comment: Was so simple was just missing `&` Thanks